# r confusion() from library mda does not output attribute error

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I don't get the same console output as described in the help of confusion() from library mda. 
It should output the following:

```
data(iris)
irisfit <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris)
confusion(predict(irisfit, iris), iris$Species)
##            Setosa Versicolor Virginica
## Setosa       50        0          0
## Versicolor    0       48          1
## Virginica     0        2         49
## attr(, "error"):
## [1] 0.02
```

However, with the same code I only get the matrix but not the error attribute. This is a bit annoying cause I have to write xtra code everytime to get the error.
To get the error I have to write an extra line like this:

```
attr(confusion(predict(irisfit, iris), iris$Species),'error')
```

What is wrong, that I don't get the same console output? The only thing I found out is that a friend of mine is getting the correct output with r version 3.2.x, with 3.3.x and 3.4.x it does not work. The mda package was created with 3.3.3.

regards Cédéric